# List operations in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, swi-prolog

I just started learning prolog so those are probably newbie questions.
My question is this. Using these 2 pieces of code I get errors:

```
X = .(1,.(2,.(3,[]))).

.(X,Y) = [1,2,3].
```

I expect after the first line `X=[1,2,3]` and after the second `X=1` and `Y=[2,3]`.

Instead I get this errors:

```
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] throw(error(instantiation_error,_3540))
ERROR:    [9] '$dicts':'.'(_3570,_3572,_3574) at c:/program files/swipl/boot/dicts.pl:46
ERROR:    [8] '<meta-call>'(user:(...,...)) <foreign>
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

I am using SWI-Prolog environment for windows 10. Why is this happening?

Comment: Look at the swi manual: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=f((%27.%27)/2)

Comment: This is a common problem and noted in many [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprolog%5D+Type+error%3A+%60dict%27+expected)

Comment: Add `--traditional` to the command line

Answer (score 1):

SWI-Prolog does something different with lists. Instead of `.` it uses `'[|]'`. So take your first example:

```
?- X = .(1, .(2, .(3, []))).
```

and replace every `.(A, B)` with `'[|]'(A, B)` to get:

```
?- X = '[|]'(1,'[|]'(2,'[|]'(3,[]))).
X = [1, 2, 3].
```

The other one becomes:

```
?- '[|]'(X, Y) = [1, 2, 3].
X = 1,
Y = [2, 3].
```